# Phonegap + Sencha + Ext.List

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

I want to build an android app which is written in Sencha with Phonegap.
Works fine but Ext.List is not displayed. Does anyone had the same problem and a solution?

I have a TabPanel with 5 Elements. One of them is Home which is a Ext.List. The data from the list comes from a store. This is working fine in the browser but if I try to build it for Android with PhoneGap this list does not appear. Just the HTML which is mentioned further down.

```
var mainMnu = new Ext.TabPanel(
    {tabBar : {
    dock : 'bottom',
            layout : {
            pack : 'center'
        }
    },
    items : [
    {
        title : 'Home',
        html : '<h1>Welcome Home</h1>',
        iconCls : 'home',
        cls : 'card1',
        dockedItems: [pnlLstHome]
    }, .....

lstHome = new Ext.List( {
    grouped : false,
    indexBar : false,
    id : 'idLstHome',
    cls: 'homeList',
    store : lstStoreMnu,
    itemTpl : '<div class="list">{item}</div>',
    onItemDisclosure : false,
    onItemSelect : function(record, btn, index) {
        // console.log(record.data);
        switch (record.data.item) {
        case constStoreMnuGalerie:
            pnlLstHome.setActiveItem('idPnlGalerie');
            // detailPanel.update(record.data);// detailPanel.doLayout();
            break;
        case constStoreMnuTrends:
            pnlLstHome.setActiveItem('idPnlTrends');
            // detailPanel.update(record.data);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('You clicked Unknown Item!');
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

**DataStore**

```
lstStoreMnu = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'list',
    //sorters: 'item', //Sortierung
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('item')[0];
    },
    data: [
           { item: constStoreMnuGalerie},
           { item: constStoreMnuTrends},
           { item: constStoreMnuPreise},
           { item: constStoreMnuProdukte},
           { item: constStoreMnuOpen},
           { item: constStoreMnuShare}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Can u please mention your problem more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the list as a **dockedItem**

Try adding it as an **item** ie

```
 {
        title : 'Home',
       // html : '<h1>Welcome Home</h1>',
        iconCls : 'home',
        cls : 'card1',
        items: [pnlLstHome]
    }
```

Hope it will help...

Comment: Sorry but it did not work :( Fascinating is that if I switch my phone horizontal the List is displayed! Any idea?